# Extract text from pdf by a specific area

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, text-extraction, pdf-extraction

As the question says I want to extract a text from a specific position using itext7 c#
so the thing is I wrote this code :

```cs
PdfReader pdfRead = new PdfReader(file);
PdfDocument pdfdoc = new PdfDocument(pdfRead);
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle((float)4.090625, (float)58.384375, (float)76.60625, (float)40.1625);
TextRegionEventFilter regionFilter = new TextRegionEventFilter(rect);
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

for (int page = 1; page <= pdfdoc.GetNumberOfPages(); page++)
{
    ITextExtractionStrategy strat = new FilteredTextEventListener(new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), regionFilter);
    string str = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfdoc.GetPage(page), strat);
    Debug.WriteLine(str);
}
```

It extracts the text from that rectangle but it wouldn't extract the area I want it just extracts a text randomly even if I give it the right coordinates, I tried another library and it gave me the text from those coordinates but in itext7 it wouldn't work.
Can anyone tell me if my code is wrong or not and what can i do to make it work i would appreciate it

Comment: *"it just extracts a text randomly even if I give it the right coordinates"* - "randomly" is not plausible. Can you share example PDFs that illustrate such randomness?

Comment: yes heres the pdf i am using https://www.docdroid.net/YsBTKuc/exe-pdf

Comment: If you wrap the strategy in a `GlyphTextEventListener`, i.e. if you use `strat = new GlyphTextEventListener(new FilteredTextEventListener(new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), regionFilter))`, are the results then as expected or do you still see issues? (Unfortunately you did not say what result you expected, so I cannot be sure whether this change is what you need or not.)

Comment: it still didnt work :/ the thing is i want to extract a text from that specific rectangle, when i used another library it worked like charm, it extracted text from that rectangular area but with itext7 it gives me an extracted text from a random position not from the rectangular one. I hope you understood what i mean

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Your coordinates describe exactly the area near the bottom left corner that is extracted, see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzBdN.png).

Comment: yes thats exactly the extracted text i keep getting, i dont know how is that possible because when i used another library with the same coordinates it gave me this rectangle instead : https://imgur.com/a/tPBaGUU

Comment: That means that that other library uses a different coordinate system. iText uses the PDF default user space coordinates (x coordinates increasing to the right, y coordinates increasing upwards, the origin potentially anywhere but often in the lower left corner). Some PDF processors prefer to use other coordinate systems, e.g. a system more often seen when processing _bitmap_ graphics with the origin in the _upper_ left and the y coordinates increasing _downwards_. When using different PDF processors, you may have to apply coordinate transformations.

Comment: ahh i see im gonna try and see if i can make it workout thank you so much tho for answering me this whole time i really apperciate it